# Exclude file from Gradle test dependency

Tags: gradle

I have rather expensive tests in my gradle java project, so I would like to avoid running them too often. Unfortunately, gradle reruns the tests on every build, since some log file in the resource-folder is changing.

Is there any way to exclude log-files from the dependency checks of `:processTestResources` and `:test`? I tried to include a `exclude` command in my `test` task, but this doesn't seem to do anything. My `test` task is

```
test {
    maxHeapSize = "2048m"
    workingDir = "src/test/resources/test-instance"
    environment "LD_LIBRARY_PATH", "xpressmp/lib:/opt/gurobi/linux64/lib"
    environment "XPRESS", "xpressmp/bin"
    environment "XPRESSDIR", "xpressmp"
    exclude("*.log")
    exclude("*.lp")
}
```

Comment: You might consider not having a log file in the source folders.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are after is

```
sourceSets {
    test {
        resources {
            exclude '*.log'
        }
    }
}
```

Excluding in the task would only exclude the test class from running, not which files are considered input for the task.

Btw. you can also use JUnit Categories to separate your tests into Short-Running and Long-Running tests and then make different tasks or a project property to only run the fast tests or all tests or only the slow tests. Or you can split the tests in different sourcesets and make separate tasks for it.

Answer (score 1):

Define a new `Test` task:

```
task notGenericNotFT( type: Test, dependsOn: testClasses ){
    filter { excludeTestsMatching 'generic.*' } 
    // excludes a whole package, "generic". NB this is not a regex:
    // '*' is simply "wildcard" and dot means dot ... other more 
    // sophisticated "ANT-style" patterns are available in class Test

    filter { excludeTestsMatching '*_FT' } 
    // also exclude all test classes ending in "_FT" (e.g. for "functional test")
}
```

To understand where these things come from, examine class [Test](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/Test.html) and class [TestFilter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html).

Also be aware that the gradle command line parser is quite intelligent and permissive with case-sensitivity (even in Linux!), so you can do this:

```
...$ ./gradlew notgen
```

... and it will run (as long as "notgen" designates this task unambiguously).